# Laravel Jetstream no able to install and its returning below error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-jetstream

kage operations: 9 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Installing dasprid/enum (1.0.3): Extracting archive
  Install of dasprid/enum failed
- Installing bacon/bacon-qr-code (2.0.3): Extracting archive
  Install of bacon/bacon-qr-code failed
- Installing jaybizzle/crawler-detect (v1.2.103): Extracting archive
  Install of jaybizzle/crawler-detect failed
- Installing paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v2.4.0): Extracting archive
  Install of paragonie/constant_time_encoding failed
- Installing pragmarx/google2fa (8.0.0): Extracting archive
  Install of pragmarx/google2fa failed
- Installing laravel/fortify (v1.7.2): Extracting archive
  Install of laravel/fortify failed
- Installing mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib (2.8.34): Extracting archive
  Install of mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib failed
- Installing jenssegers/agent (v2.6.4): Extracting archive
  Install of jenssegers/agent failed
- Installing laravel/jetstream (v1.6.4): Extracting archive
  Install of laravel/jetstream failed
  0 [>---------------------------]
  Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

[UnexpectedValueException]
'F:\xampp\htdocs\example-jetstream/vendor/composer/tmp-9693892fd8e6eedc22c7fc7b94f0876e' is not a zip archive.

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...

Comment: do you have enough disk space?

Comment: Could be your network, the disk space, ... https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1242

Comment: Have you tried running `composer clearcache`?